# Bad device token apple push notification

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have stuck in apple push notification. Following the document in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1 I created the header and payload with the private key to generate token, but after call api:  https://api.development.push.apple.com:443/3/device/, It told bad device token. Check in jwt.io it said invalid token.
Anyone know this problem or idea.
Thank you !

Here is the code .net core:

```
var header = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { alg = "ES256", kid = keyId });
var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { iss = teamId, iat = ToEpoch(DateTime.UtcNow) });
var key = CngKey.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(p8privateKey), CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);
            using (ECDsaCng dsa = new ECDsaCng(key))
            {
                dsa.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
                var headerBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header));
                var payloadBasae64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
                var unsignedJwtData = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header)) + "." + System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
                var unsignedJwtDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unsignedJwtData);
                var signature =
                dsa.SignData(unsignedJwtDataBytes);
                return unsignedJwtData + "." + System.Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
            }
        }
```

Comment: "bad device token" is probably referring to the APNS token in the URI, not the JWT Authorization header.

Comment: I saw the apns-id, if it's empty, it'll generate random apns-id like guid Id